# Counting words from array in a string

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of string say

```
A=["hello", "you"]
```

I have a string, say

```
s="hello, hello you are so wonderful"
```

I need to count the number of occurrence of strings from `A` in `s`.
In this case, the number of occurrences is 3 (2 `"hello"`, 1 `"you"`).

How to do this effectively? (`A` might contains lots of words, and `s` might be long in practice)

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted?

Comment: iterate over the array, for each word, count the occurences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void countMatches() {
    String[] A = {"hello", "you"};
    String s = "hello, hello you are so wonderful";
    String patternString = "(" + StringUtils.join(A, "|")   + ")";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

Note that StringUtils is from apache commons. If you don't want to include and additional jar you can just construct that string using a for loop.

Comment: In Java 8, you can say [`String.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)`("|",A)`.  No more need for Apache Commons.

Comment: P.S. I would add `"\\b"` to both sides of `patternString`, depending on the exact requirements.

Comment: Yes we can. I thought of a sub string search. Additionally we can ignore case as well. All based on requirements.

Comment: I end up using this method, which is more flexible, one thing I am not sure is the efficiency of pattern matching provided by Java given many words in array A.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
for(String a : dictionnary) {
    wordCount.put(a, 0);
}
for(String s : text.split("\\s+")) {
    Integer count = wordCount.get(s);
    if(count != null) {
        wordCount.put(s, count + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int count =0;
for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
{
  count = count + s.split(A[i],-1).length - 1;
}
```

Working Ideone : http://ideone.com/Z9K3JX

Answer (score 1):

```
HashSet<String> searchWords = new HashSet<String>();

for(String a : dictionary) {
    searchWords.add(a);
}

int count = 0;

for(String s : input.split("[ ,]")) {
    if(searchWords.contains(s)) {
       count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should be `"[ ,]+"`, i.e. split on a comma sequence of length one _or more_.  But your way just puts extra empty strings in the result array which is harmless.

Comment: I like this solution, as (1) t could split the string against some delimiters of our choice, and (2) the complexity is almost O(n)

Comment: I think the complexity is O(n+m) where n is the number of words in the dictionary and m is the number of words in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This is fully working method with output :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] A={"hello", "you"};
    String s= "hello, hello you are so wonderful";
    int[] count = new int[A.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        count[i] = (s.length() - s.replaceAll(A[i], "").length())/A[i].length();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(A[i] + ": " + count[i]);
    }
}
```

---

What does this line do?

`count[i] = (s.length() - s.replaceAll(A[i], "").length())/A[i].length();`

This part `s.replaceAll(A[i], "")` changes all "hello" to empty "" string in the text.

So I take the length of everything `s.length()` I substract from it the length of same string without that word `s.replaceAll(A[i], "").length()` and I divide it by the length of that word `/A[i].length()`

---

**Sample output for this example :**

```
hello: 2
you: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [String Tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Do something like this:

```
A = ["hello", "you"];
s = "hello, hello you are so wonderful";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        for (String i: A) {
            if(st.nextToken() == i){
                //You can keep going from here
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

It doesn't create any new objects. It uses [`String.indexOf(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), keeps track of the current index, and increments the occurance-count.

```
public class SearchWordCount  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      String[] searchWords = {"hello", "you"};
      String input = "hello, hello you are so wonderful";

      for(int i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++)  {
         String searchWord = searchWords[i];

         System.out.print(searchWord + ": ");

         int foundCount = 0;
         int currIdx = 0;
         while(currIdx != -1)  {
            currIdx = input.indexOf(searchWord, currIdx);

            if(currIdx != -1)  {
               foundCount++;
               currIdx += searchWord.length();
            }  else  {
               currIdx = -1;
            }
         }

         System.out.println(foundCount);

      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
hello: 2
you: 1
```